# MySQL select data and split result on certain criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I Have my table with bids.

```
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
| id | auctionID | bidderID | amount  | bidTime                  | pr   |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
|  5 |         3 |        3 | 1000000 | 2016-10-18 21:59:36.0000 |   25 |
|  6 |         4 |        1 |  100000 | 2016-10-20 23:29:12.0000 |   30 |
|  7 |         4 |        2 |  100000 | 2016-10-20 23:29:25.3352 |   25 |
|  8 |         4 |        3 |  500000 | 2016-10-20 23:30:09.0000 |   50 |
|  9 |         3 |        2 |  250000 | 2016-10-20 23:54:26.0000 |   25 |
| 10 |         3 |        1 | 5000000 | 2016-10-21 03:56:00.0000 |   60 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
```

I need output for one auctionID (this time 3), first priority is pr, second is bidTime.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE auctionID = 3 ORDER BY pr DESC, bidTime ASC;
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
| id | auctionID | bidderID | amount  | bidTime                  | pr   |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
| 10 |         3 |        1 | 5000000 | 2016-10-21 03:56:00.0000 |   60 |
|  5 |         3 |        3 | 1000000 | 2016-10-18 21:59:36.0000 |   25 |
|  9 |         3 |        2 |  250000 | 2016-10-20 23:54:26.0000 |   25 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
```

So far so good.

Now i need to split this select to winning and non-winning bids based ON amount. Let`s say max total amount for auction 3 is set to 5500000. In this case bid with id=5 must be splitted in half.

Example output, i am looking for (winning bids vs loosing bids with split on required amount, in this case 5500000):

```
SELECT winningBids;
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
| id | auctionID | bidderID | amount  | bidTime                  | pr   |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
| 10 |         3 |        1 | 5000000 | 2016-10-21 03:56:00.0000 |   60 |
|  5 |         3 |        3 |  500000 | 2016-10-18 21:59:36.0000 |   25 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+

SELECT loosingBids;
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
| id | auctionID | bidderID | amount  | bidTime                  | pr   |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
|  5 |         3 |        3 |  500000 | 2016-10-18 21:59:36.0000 |   25 |
|  9 |         3 |        2 |  250000 | 2016-10-20 23:54:26.0000 |   25 |
+----+-----------+----------+---------+--------------------------+------+
```

I know ho to do it with PHP/MySQL, but i am looking for doing this in MySQL only.

Thank you

Comment: mysql can't produce rows out of nothing. this is something you'll have to do in client-side code.

Comment: You should separate your data storage from your business logic, this shouldn't be done in MySQL.